# Add interceptor programmatically on server

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, interceptor

although I've searched in the documentation it seems I'm missing something.
I'm publishing a web service through a configuration file. Ok the service is up and running.
Now I'm trying to add some custom interceptors programmatically. Let's say the class that is my
main class that has the enpoint method is called TestImpl, and the web service method testWS(). If I wanted to add ingoing and outgoing interceptors for this service where should I do that? In the constructor? How would I do that? In which provider? Service, Endpoint, Bus, Binding? Thank you for your help.

Right now I'm doing

```
    ServerFactoryBean serverFactoryBean = new ServerFactoryBean();

    Server server = serverFactoryBean.create();

    server.getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(new CustomLoggingInInterceptor());
    server.getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(new CustomLoggingOutInterceptor());
```

In the constructor of my class but I'm receiving a NullPointerException in `Server server = serverFactoryBean.create();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CXF support to setup the interceptors from the Bus, Binding, and endpoint.

When you call the serverFactoryBean.create(), the server is created and open for business.
You can setup the intercepter directly on the serverFactoryBean before calling the create method.

BTW, you need also setup address and serviceClass() if you are using ServerFactoryBean.

Comment: Do you have any reference, any link I could read more on this? What I want to accomplish is to put my custom interceptors programmatically in a server service and I haven't found an example that is complete and simple.

Comment: Here is the example that you can take a look http://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html.

Comment: This is publishing the service programmatically. I publish it through the web.xml config file of my webapp. If I want to add the interceptors programmatically I'm forced to publish the service programmatically too? Upvoted because you partly answered my question. Please answer this part too, and I will accept your asnwer.

Comment: You can take a look at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html#ServletTransport-UsingtheservlettransportwithoutSpring

Comment: I took a look, but I still don't have an answer.

Comment: If you want to publish the service by using web.xml, I guess you don't want to use spring to load the information about the jaxws endpoint, and you are trying to use JAXWS frontend API to publish the service, then you can extends the CXFNonSpringServlet to setup the ServerFactoryBean and interceptors that way.